# onelogin javasaml 2.0 in java6 project

Tags: java, saml-2.0, onelogin

I have a old project running in java 6 and am trying to implement sso using onelogin's javasaml library. I see the java-saml-core and java-saml dependencies compiled with higher versions. I also see that in the github that it is compatable with java 6,7 and 8. What does it mean? May i use the libraries as it is to develop my solution in java6 project? any thoughts? thank you!

https://github.com/onelogin/java-saml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Version 2.X of java-saml was originally designed to be compatible with Java 6,7 and 8.

but in the road we introduced some incompatibilities with Java 6 that we described on that [github issue](https://github.com/onelogin/java-saml/issues/90)

Comment: does it mean that i cannot use with java6? seems like so due to ACCESS_EXTERNAL_DTD and ACCESS_EXTERNAL_SCHEMA. or is there an workaround? thank you

Comment: The workaround is described on the github thread... you will need to make some modifications on the code :(

Comment: @rrunique I would like to make java-saml to work with Java 6. Did you managed to get it working with Java 6?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone is interested, I managed to recompile java-saml under Java 6 to run on an old WebSphere instance.

Changes are limited to a few Java 7 specific syntax (diamonds, multi catch, closeable)

Fork is available at: https://github.com/mguessan/java-saml

Comment: I am trying to compile it with java 6 but there are still some references to java 7. Can i have a look at your compiled project?

Comment: Checked again and indeed found a few Java > 6 calls, easy to replace. Also added an appveyor configuration to build automatically for Java 1.6 https://ci.appveyor.com/project/mguessan/java-saml, note that it appears that Maven no longer works with Java 1.6, but this shouldn't be an issue

Comment: i saw there are some commit to the master branch. I think there is still reference to java 7.
if (JAXP_15_SUPPORTED) {
    // Prevent XXE attacks
    validator.setProperty(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_DTD, "");
    validator.setProperty(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_SCHEMA, "");
   }

Comment: Yes, noticed this, as it explicitly checks for JAXP 1.5 support I assumed it should not be an issue, did you try it ?

Comment: I can’t run the project as this is showing as error on eclipse. Or can i comment this out?

Comment: Well, I don't eclipse so won't help you on this. Basically you need to build under Java 1.8 (with a Java 1.6 target) and disable tests (fail on windows) => build is definitely working, see: https://ci.appveyor.com/project/mguessan/java-saml/build/job/5nnkvxbbumwto5xi

Comment: I am using java 1.6 for the build and maybe that is why not working. After I used java 1.8 to build, and target as java 1.6, working good now. many thanks for your help!